# ¿ Cómo graficar un angulo en matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

por motivo de una evaluacion en la universidad, estoy desarrollando una simulacion de un robot con dos articulaciones, esto implica deducir sus ecuaciones de cinematica directa e inversa. Esto no es un problema, ya que lo he resuelto, además, la evaluacion solicita generar trayectorias en base a posiciones y utilizar las funciones de cinematica inversa para calcular los angulos que cada segmento del robot debe tomar para tener tal posicion, para facilitarme la tarea, he incluido la grafica de los segmentos del robot en un grafico utilizando el modulo matplotlib.

Nada de esto es el problema, y ya se encuentra desarrollado en codigo, el problema realmente reside en que no he encontrado en internet ni en videos de youtube alguna forma de graficar los angulos de manera facil, inmediata y por medio de clase, metodo o funcion dentro del modulo matplotlib.

¿ Matplotlib permite graficar angulos con algun metodo rapido?
esto lo planteo ya que si no se encuentra disponible este recurso tendria que recurrir a artimañas para mostrar algo que parezca un angulo en la grafica.

Adjunto una imagen de lo desarrollado hasta el momento con tal de que entiendan lo que busco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los puntos azules son las posiciones de la trayectoria, los segmentos blancos es el segmento A del robot, el segmento negro es el segmento B del robot, los circulos verdes son el area de trabajo que tendria el robot segun la configuracion de sus segmentos.

Entonces, lo que yo busco es poder agregar el angulo que tienen los segmentos en cada configuracion del robot con tal de tener retroalimentacion y facilitar el desarrollo del resto de la actividad.

Comment: Tal vez con arc https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html